# Convergence of an Iterative Algorithm

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I am considering a very simple problem for finding a common point to the two sets $A$ and $B$ where $A$ is the $x$-axis and $B$ is the line $y=x$. The algorithm used is that of alternating projections. Consider $P_Bx$ and $P_Ax$ to be the projection of $x$ onto the sets $B$ and $A$ respectively. Then the iteration used will be 
$$T_{A,B}x=P_AP_Bx$$
I am interested in the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{||x_{n+1}||}{||x_{n}||}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{||P_AP_Bx_n||}{||x_n||}$$
Now if $x_n=(\alpha_n,\beta_n)$ then $$P_AP_Bx_n=(\frac{\alpha_n+\beta_n}{2},0)$$
Thus 
$$||P_AP_Bx_n||=\left| \frac{\alpha_n+\beta_n}{2}\right|$$
and so 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{||x_{n+1}||}{||x_{n}||}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|\alpha_n+\beta_n|}{2\sqrt{\alpha_n^2+\beta_n^2}}$$
but I am unsure as to how to compute the limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recursively evaluate your expression from $x_0=(\alpha, \beta)$ which gives 
$$x_{n+1} = \left(\frac{\alpha_n+\beta_n}{2} , 0\right) = \left(\frac{(\frac{\alpha_{n-1}+\beta_{n-1}}{2})+0}{2} , 0\right)$$
Which gives you
$$x_n =  \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2^n} , 0 \right)$$
Which as expected gives that the whole algo converges to 0 with ratio $\frac{1}{2}$ between successive terms constantly.

If it confuses you, it might be because you wanted to have a limit rather than the speed with which you converge?

Comment: I didn't think to perform the iteration, it seems so obvious now - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misinterpreting the question, I believe that $\beta$ should always be 0, since every iteration concludes with a projection onto the $x$-axis.

So if we remove the $\beta$ term and focus on the effect of the dual projections on the $x$-coordinate, we see that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.